# QGIS Atlas fit center map to another table

Tags: qgis, scale, atlas

In QGIS Atlas, I manage two tables. One regarding buildings sector with its own geometry at sector level. The other regarding buildings. Both tables are related by sector code.
I need one map per building but centered on the sector.
Now what I have is a map per building centered on building since Atlas has to be controlled by building layer. [image]

Answer (score 4):

You can have two solution one with new layer, one with code.

### Solution 1 : Use a layer with the building attribute table and with the sector as geometry.

Use the tool `join attribute by field value` with the sector as `input layer` and the building as `input layer 2`. Then use this layer as `coverage layer` you can use the option `Hidden coverage layer`. Then you can adapt the building layer style to be depend on the current atlas feature. You can activate the red line on the building concerned by your atlas with this formula : `attribute (@atlas_feature ,'my_building_id') = "my_building_id"`.

Note : the join process normally have copied your building id field but the name of the field could be different of the source layer if you have a field with same name in your sector layer.

The limit : you have to update a new layer for each modification.

### Solution 2 : Use `extents` based on data and not `controlled by atlas`.

[image]

1. Uncheck controlled by atlas
2. Define extent `X min` `Y min` `X max` `Y max` based on data.
3. The expression should get the sector feature related with `get_feature(` then the geometry and evaluate the `X min` `Y min` `X max` `Y max`.

```
x_min( geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))) - 100
y_min( geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))) - 100
x_max( geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))) + 100
y_max( geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))) + 100
```

- Replace `SECTOR_LAYER` with your sector layer name or id.
- Replace `sector_id_1` with the name of sector id field in the sector layer.
- Replace `sector_id_2` with the name of sector id field in the building layer (use for atlas).
- You will not have the 10% margin around, so you have to add margin in meter. Replace `100` with the number of map unit you want between your sector and the border of the map.

The limit : you have a fixed size margin which will not be suited if your sector have very different scale.

To get a margin depending on your feature size in percent you could calculate it in your expression based on min and max to get the size. Here is an example to get 10 percent for `X min`, `Y min`, `X max` and `Y max`.

```
x_min( geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))) 
- 10 / 100 *(bounds_width(geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))))

y_min( geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))) 
- 10 / 100 *(bounds_height(geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))))

x_max( geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))) 
+ 10 / 100 *(bounds_width(geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))))

y_max( geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))) 
+ 10 / 100 *(bounds_height(geometry( get_feature( 'SECTOR_LAYER' , 'sector_id_1', "sector_id_2"))))
```

Comment: I'm thinking the margin could easily be based on a proportion of the height and width for the particular geometry's bounding box to make it adaptive.

Comment: I was lazy and didn't add it on the post. Now i have modified the post to get margin in percent.

Comment: First option works well but I rather to get for the second because there is no limitations. I'm not finding the right sintaxi I guess because obtained value is null. What I am writing is: x_min(geometry(get_feature('scg_sectors',"fases", "fases")))-100. Seems strange "fases" don't need to specify its table. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for the answer. It solved the problem.

Comment: There is at least one mistake you have made : you have to use simple quote for the first (a string that is equal to your field name in the table you specified before) and double quotes for the second (it will be replaced by the content of the attribute fase on your actual atlas feature). It should be : `x_min(geometry(get_feature('scg_sectors','fases', "fases")))-100`. If it doesn't work, you could do it step by step and split the expression to get a result. You could try first `get_feature('scg_sectors','fases', "fases")` you should get a feature as output.

Comment: simple quote! awesome!